# How to avoid Current column to appear for every week?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a .pbix where I show current  week + next 2 weeks data…

My values:

[image]

Filters:

[image]

My challenge is that I want to show ‘Current Project’, ‘Proposed Project’ and ‘BIO link’ only once and not for every week...

So, the only solution I found so far, is to manually hide them, every time a new week appears:

[image]

It’s a bit time consuming… has anyone found a simpler solution to this?

DAX code of ‘Current Project’ and ‘Proposed Project’ respectively:

```
CALCULATE (

CONCATENATEX (DISTINCT ( DimProjects[Project] ),        DimProjects [Project],  ", "   ),

    FILTER ( FactStaff, FactStaff [IsConfirmed] = TRUE )

)

 

 

CALCULATE (

 CONCATENATEX (DISTINCT ( DimProjects [Project] ),  DimProjects [Project],  ", "   ),

    FILTER ( FactStaff, FactStaff[IsConfirmed] = FALSE() )

)
```

This is what I have:
[image]

I am trying to achieve this:
[image]

I do achieve the result I want myself. But I achieve it, by hiding the columns (resizing to 0.001 width manually).

This is very time consuming; and I have to do it every week, because, of course, the WeekOffset changes...

Comment: Can you share your pbix file ?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible at this time.

I would try to add the BioLink to the %Staffed and the Current Project and Proposed project as Tooltips.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the weeks as your column field. You can make a measure that calculates the %-staffed for the current week, current week +1, etc.

```
Sales Next week = 
    var _week = MAX(DimDate[Next Year Week])
    return
    CALCULATE(SUM(Fact_InternetSales[SalesAmount]), FILTER(ALL(DimDate), DimDate[YearAndWeek] = _week))
```

This measure uses the DimDate column Next Year Week. This column shows the next week in a YYYYWW format. If you need 1 more week you can add another column to your DimDate that will show the week after that in the YYYYWW format.

The following power BI file uses the same method based on the Microsoft Adventureworks Internetsales demo dataset:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/11IPnVL8lsOj66YZWIkkjh7xVdS1fvKEK/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please make the link accessible :)